# Can't connect to dockerized mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm dockerizing an adonisjs + mysql application. I created a docker-compose and Dockerfile and everything was working just fine, but I wanted to move all those files instead a dedicated directory. Now docker containers are being built and everything starts but I just cannot connect to my MySQL docker.

When I try to connect it always says "Access denied for user 'homestead'@'172.30.0.1' (using password: YES)".
The fun fact is that it always puts that 172.30.0.1 it wasn't like this before and it always tries to connect to that host even when I specifically say to connect to localhost.

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: "${APP_NAME}-mysql"
    build: ./mysql
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:3306"
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - api-network
  api:
    container_name: "${APP_NAME}-api"
    build:
      context: ../.
      dockerfile: ./deploy/api/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ../.:/app
    environment:
      - HOST=0.0.0.0  # listen on all interfaces
      - SERVER_ENV=development
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:80"     # matches actual listener message
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - api-network

networks:
  api-network:

volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: "local"
```

This is the `Dockerfile` for Mysql

```
FROM mysql:5.7

COPY custom.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/custom.cnf

CMD ["mysqld"]

EXPOSE 3306
```

This is my `custom.cnf`

```
[mysqld]

open-files-limit        = 24000
key_buffer_size         = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 1000M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8

#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M

#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!

innodb_fast_shutdown                = 1
innodb_data_file_path               = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_file_per_table               = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size             = 1G # The most important variable here
innodb_log_file_size                = 128M
innodb_log_buffer_size              = 32M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit      = 2
innodb_lock_wait_timeout            = 50
innodb_flush_method                 = O_DIRECT
innodb_thread_concurrency           = 4
innodb_use_native_aio               = 0
```

This is the API `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12.18.2-alpine3.9

MAINTAINER Dan Rusnac <dan@genuino.world>

ENV HOME=/app
RUN mkdir /app

COPY . $HOME
COPY package.json $HOME

WORKDIR $HOME
RUN npm i -g @adonisjs/cli && npm install

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

This is the output of `docker ps`:

```
dan@dan-Nitro-AN515-54:~/Documents/Tests/testProject$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
4457681caf98        deploy_api          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 hours ago        Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                  testProject-api
6348bef9fc22        deploy_mysql        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 hours ago        Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   testProject-mysql
```

My .env

```
HOST=127.0.0.1
PORT=80
NODE_ENV=development
APP_URL=http://${HOST}:${PORT}
APP_NAME=testProject

CACHE_VIEWS=false
APP_KEY=

SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
HASH_DRIVER=bcrypt

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=172.17.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_USER=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=Secret1234
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: How is your API's connection string? Did you try to declare the mysql_user and password?                            `MYSQL_USER: mysqluser
 MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysqlpassword`

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. I tried to add the MySQL user and password but it still didn't work.
What do you mean by "API connection string"?

Comment: What I noticed is that everytime I prune the images and rebuild everything the MySQL host increases. Eg:
At first it says 'Access denied for user 'homestead'@'172.30.0.1' , then 172.31.0.1, then 172.32.0.1 and so on. Shouldn't the host be 127.0.0.1?

Comment: I fixed this by assigning mysql environment variables directly inside the docker file instead of taking them from the env. So by doing `MYSQL_USER=myuser` instead of `MYSQL_USER=${DB_USER}`. 
I think docker-compose file wasn't able to read those values.
Thank you for your help @abestrad